# How to disable a button, if it is clicked once in a day and enable on next day using JavaScript and AngularJS 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My button should be disabled once I clicked in a day (i.e) only once in a day a user enter the details using submit button. Next day automatically button should be enabled.

Help me with JavaScript or AngularJS..

Comment: Look into cookies.

Comment: You should maintain the state in database

Comment: Best way you can do it from the frontend is by storing the data in cookies or localStorage, however they can be easily deleted by anyone and because they are stored in the client's browser, if someone use another web browser or other device it will allow them to click the button again. So you should consider using database for that as Sajal said.

Answer (score 2):

If you have backend you could maintain state in DB as Sajal said, but since you are asking about angularjs/javascript and frontend solution cookies (what Chris said) or localStorage is  way to go, set the cookie and based on cookie you can set button each day to reset

more info on w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Keep in mind cookies can be modified so DB is best way if you want fullproof solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the status of the click in the localstorage, but this solution is unsafe.
You should add a server side control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeout functionality. You can give specific time for timeout then after that timeout you can enable the button.

**EX:**

```
var theInterval = $interval(function(){
      //Enable button
   }.bind(this), time);
```

Comment: This solution would require user to keep his browser opened, so it's really edge case that this would actually work.

Comment: yes for this user need to keep his open the browser. for this you can store the time in local storage and when browser will open then it will calculate the remaining time for enable of button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *localStorage* :

```
<button ng-disabled="!buttonIsActive()" ng-click="onClick()"></button>

$scope.buttonIsActive = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    var lastClickDay = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("last-click-day"));        
    return day > lastClickDay;
}

$scope.onClick = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    localStorage.setItem("last-click-day", day);
    // ... Do something else here
}
```